# Android Push Notification to make different type of notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'am already have my own android app, and I'am working to add the push notification service to my app. Using the GCM (google clouding messaging). My problem is how I can push different type notifications to my app users ? 
More explanation, for example I want to push a notification that redirect the users to my website for an offer. And then I want to push another one that tell the users about my new store branch.
How could I do this exactly.

Thank A lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging gives you the ability to send up to 4kb of data. Using the payload you can deliver message specific actions to accomplish what you want.
For instance, you can add the the JSON a field **custom_action** and **custom_url** to determine in your app when and how to handle each event.

You should always give the user the ability to choose whether or not to be redirected 'cause that behavior can be very annoying.

Hope it helps.